# Django upload image - From a form to Rackspace/S3 with no manipulation

Tags: python, django, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I simply want to upload an image (JPG) using a form, then send that image to Rackspace 'Cloud Files' or Amazon 'S3'.

- No manipulating the file.
- No saving to disk, everything to memory (am hosted on a cloud server)
- Image size won't exceed 75kb

**Update** (Two Caveats):

- One: It also needs to work when data is posted from a phone app.
- Two: It needs to be sent to Rackspace Cloud Files as well as S3 (starting with CF).

The code below works but it is way WAY too heavy.

```
import cloudfiles as cf
def uploadImage(request, id):

  cf_con = cf.get_connection(username='YYY', api_key='XXX', serviceNet=True)
  container = cf_con.get_container('container_name')

  file = request.FILES["item_photo"]
  f = StringIO(file.read())
  f = Image.open(f)

  ### Only works if I resize for some reason, otherwise uploads a broken file
  image = f.resize((600,600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  o = StringIO()
  image.save(o, "JPEG", quality=80)
  image = o.getvalue()

  file_name  = "%s/%s" % (id, '600x600.jpeg')

  ### This simply uploads to Rackspace Cloud files.
  put_file(container, file_name, image)
```

Thanks so much,
Hope all is well ...

d.

Comment: I'm confused, your example code resizes the image but your description says _No manipulating the file_.  Which is it?  If you want to resize the image then a lot of what you're doing is necessary.

Comment: Thanks @stuart, I don't want to resize the image, I was trying to upload without the manipulation but it uploaded a broken file, the code above works but is too heavy and forces a resize. In a perfect world I'd love to simply:

`file = request.FILES["item_photo"]`
`file_name  = "%s/%s" % (id, '600x600.jpeg')`
`put_file(container, file_name, file)`

But that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

How about ignoring python all together and just uploading directly to s3?

You can configure your s3 bucket to disallow uploading any files larger than $X bytes.

Here's a simple example to illustrate uploading directly to s3 (and ignoring your image width/height conditions)

http://sente.cc/upload_to_s3.html

code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h3>refresh the page after you've submitted to see your new image</h3>
    <div style="width:300px">
    <form action="http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.sente" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" /> <br />
      <i>name of key:</i><input type="text" name="key" readonly="true" value="image.jpg" /> <br />
      <input name="file" type="file" /> <br />
      <input name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
    <br>
    <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.sente/image.jpg">http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.sente/image.jpg</a>
      <br>
      <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.sente/image.jpg"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.sente/image.jpg"></a>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, that's pretty awesome. I hadn't thought of that. My only problem is two caveats.
 - One: It also needs to work when data is posted from a phone app.
 - Two: It needs to be sent to Rackspace Cloud Files.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted out.
Found a simpler elegant approach and feel stupid for not getting to it earlier.

```
file = request.FILES["item_photo"]
file_name = "%s/%s" % (id, '600.jpeg')
put_file(container, file_name, file.read())
```